# Styling text nodes without having to surround them with tags?

Tags: javascript

So usually there is only one way of styling text, that is either coloring the entire text via css (or the first word) or creating a span tag around them either manually or with createElement in order for the styling to work. My question is if there is a way to style something which only returns a string:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('something');
var charTwo = elem.charAt(2);
```

Technically this is now impossible but what if I could make this return value behave like: `<span>Character</span>`? Is this possible in javascript? If yes what api can I use?

Comment: No, HTML doesn't work that way. You have to mark off the text if you want to style it differently.

Comment: @Blazemonger so there is absolutely no way of doing this? Like making the return value behave like it had some virtual markup?

Comment: _“but what if I could make this return value behave like: Character?”_ – what’s that supposed to mean? Apart from special cases such as `:first-letter`, `:first-line` and maybe a few others, an element is the smallest “styleable unit” in the HTML & CSS universe.

Comment: Nothing I know of. The computer simply has no way of knowing you want it to be styled differently unless you wrap a tag around it.

Comment: @CBroe im aware but I thought there might be some work-around because I find it cleaner if there arent too many span elements on a page.

Comment: _“Like making the return value behave like it had some virtual markup?”_ – nope. But you could of course create an element dynamically, put your character into it as a new text node, and append both to the DOM …

Comment: @CBroe thats what I did.

Comment: _“because I find it cleaner if there arent too many span elements on a page”_ – oh, so it’s just one of “those” questions again …

Comment: element.appendChild(document.createElement('span')).textContent = 'text';

Comment: @CBroe Is it bad to ask those things? Im relatively new here so I had no idea. Im very curious about things you know

Comment: Not “bad”, no – but the _motivation_ behind the question is somewhat odd. If you have a piece of text that deserves or needs special styling – then putting it into an element of its own should be a logical thing. Browsers are made to deal with lots of elements – so unless you had some really extreme case in mind, a couple of spans just for text formatting aren’t gonna hurt.

Comment: @CBroe my case is pretty extreme ya. Lets say 10, 20, 50 maybe a hundred? In the end im doing some crazy animations with those so I thought my idea might give me a performance boost.

Comment: _“Lets say 10, 20, 50 maybe a hundred?”_ – that’s nothing to a browser … by “extreme” I meant more into the realm of maybe four or five digit numbers …